# PDO::setAttribute() doesn't seems to affect new PDO()?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this code

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_informations', 'root', '');
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

And it gives me the exception message:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'db_informations'

Because the correct name of my database is `db_information` only.

My question is, even if I don't include the line:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

I still get the same exception and I think it's not necessary to use it? Is it?

Comment: Can you clarify what *I think it's not necessary to use it?* means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply because that's the behaviour of [`PDO::__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) as you can read in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php#refsect1-pdo.construct-errors):

> **PDO::__construct()** throws a **PDOException** if the attempt to connect to the requested database fails.

But if you don't set the error mode to Exception and you do:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_informations', 'root', '');
    $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM aTableWhichDoesNotExists");
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

You won't get any excpetion message or error, because you didn't set the error mode. So you need to do this:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_informations', 'root', '');
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM aTableWhichDoesNotExists");
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

To receive an exception, which you then can catch:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test.atablewhichdoesnotexists' doesn't exist

---

Also if you just think logically:

`setAttribute()` needs to be used with `->`, which means you need an instance of the class to call that method. So how would you be able to call that method, if the instance couldn't be created correctly?

(So that would mean `setAttribute()` would have to bee static, so that you can set something/call it before you take the instance of the class)

Comment: @FewFlyBy You're welcome. (Just updated my answer with just logical thinking)

Comment: What is the instance of the class there sir? Because I'm also having problems differentiating -> from :: even if I read php oop docs..

Comment: @FewFlyBy You create a *new* instance of a class with the keyword [**new**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.new) so here you (try to)create an instance of PDO with: `new PDO()`

Comment: @FewFlyBy Maybe also take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139/3933332 There are some good questions about `::` and `->`

Comment: so  I created a new instance of the PDO class right?

Comment: @FewFlyBy Exactly, and if you do: `var_dump($dbh);` you will see that it is an instance of the class PDO: `object(PDO)` (It's the same as you would do: `$o =` **new** `StdClass();
  var_dump($o);` you will see, that `$o` is an instance of the class StdClass -> `object(stdClass)`)

Comment: Yes I understand it now, thanks. And so the scope resolution operator :: is used to access method of a class right?

Comment: @FewFlyBy `::` yes, but not only methods. It's used to only access **static** properties and methods.

Comment: Alright, because for example PDO::getAvailableDrivers();, you don't even need to create a new instance of a class to use it

Comment: @FewFlyBy Exactly, you got it! (Just don't get confused of the way php.net writes their prototypes: `public static array PDO::getAvailableDrivers ( void )` <- The `::` in the prototype doesn't mean that it is static, since php.net uses it for every class method. <- But the keyword **static** in the prototype will give away, that the method is static and called with `::`)